# Combining a counter with 2 table classes

Tags: jquery, html, counter

I have a counter of *10 when clicked on a cell for class test and a counter of *20 when clicked on a cell for class pest. How could I combine these counters so they both display in the same div? It works like, say I click on a test cell, 10 would display. If I click on another test cell, 20 would display. If I re-click on a test cell, 10 would display as the cell would be 'de-activated'. Same works for the pest cells but that would be in 20's. Right now it doesn't count it properly when I try to click both test and pest cells. any help?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='test' id='g'><img src='images/Cat.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='g'><img src='images/Dog.gif'/></td>
<td class='pest' id='e'><img src='images/Mouse.gif'/></td>
<td class='pest' id='e'><img src='images/Human.gif'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var clicked = [];
$('td.test').click(function() {
    var found = clicked.indexOf(this.id);       
    if(found !== -1) {
        clicked.splice(found, 1);       
    } else {
        clicked.push(this.id);
    }       
    $('#output').text(clicked.length*20);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
var clicked = [];
$('td.pest').click(function() {
    var found = clicked.indexOf(this.id);       
    if(found !== -1) {
        clicked.splice(found, 1);       
    } else {
        clicked.push(this.id);
    }       
    $('#output').text(clicked.length*20);
});
});
```

For Example: right now when I click on 1 test cell and 1 pest cell it displays 20 instead of 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZjsVB/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.test, td.pest').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        var testCount = $('td.test.active').length * 10;
        var pestCount = $('td.pest.active').length * 20;

        $('#output').text(testCount + pestCount);
    });
});
```

Comment: Much simpler than my code and has made some things clear to me. Thanks again

Comment: I was about to post almost the exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/3PgGb/ and then I saw yours and had déjà vu. +1